# Fotorama fullsreen and arrows button outside main container

Tags: fullscreen, fotorama

I need took out buttons from fotorama, but i cant do this with standart methods

https://i.stack.imgur.com/458w1.jpg - image what i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

i find a desigion, in new version of fotorama api, http://fotorama.io/customize/api/

It's super plugin for such work.